# antd form tag not submitting with redux form

Tags: reactjs, antd

antd `4.x`

Redux form:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from "antd"



function MyForm({ handleSubmit }) {
 
  return(
   <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  
    <Field  
     name="firstName"
     label="Name on the card"
      component={'input'}
      required
    />
  
   <Field   
     name="lastName"
     label="Name on the card"
      component={'input'}
      required
    />
   
  <Button  type="primary" htmlType="submit" > Save </Button> 
  
  </Form>
)

}
MyForm = connect()(MyForm);

MyForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'MyForm'
    
})(MyForm);

export default MyForm;
```

**Issue:**

Submit not working if I use antd `<Form>` tag, tried with onFinish, no luck

Works fine if replace with html `<form>` tag, but the styles break.

Comment: Did you try all the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773339/ant-design-form-element-is-not-submitting-when-the-form-button-is-clicked ?

Comment: @MayankPathela yes, no luck.

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi have you tried using `Form.Item` instead of `Field` and `onFinish` instead of `onSubmit`?

Comment: @mj. this is redux form, we have to pass onSubmit.